# Laravel 4 except filter in controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently I have an AdminContoller with a construct method handling some of the before filters. Is there a way to do a before filter on all controller methods except one?

I'm using Entrust for Roles and Permissions, but this code is throwing me into an infinite redirect loop. I'm not logged in as a user at all. So this code should redirect me to the /admin/login url which is attached to an unfiltered AdminController@adminLogin method. But it doesn't?

// AdminController.php file

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    function __construct() {

        // Is something like this possible?
        $this->beforeFilter('admin', array('except' => array('adminLogin')));
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return "Admin - Index";
    }

    public function adminLogin()
    {
        return "Admin Login Form";
    }

    // ... and many more methods
}
```

// Filter.php file

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if( !Entrust::hasRole('admin') ) // Checks the current user
    {
        return Redirect::to('/admin/login');
    }
});
```

// Routes.php file

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');

Route::get('/admin/login', 'AdminController@adminLogin');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've added a new method into a resourceful controller, you should register the new method first, before the resource.

E.g.

```
<?php // Routes.php

Route::get('/admin/login', 'AdminController@adminLogin');
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

This way your before filters should work as you have then like this:

```
<?php // AdminController.php
   class AdminController extends BaseController {
     function __construct() {
       $this->beforeFilter('admin', array('except' => array('adminLogin')));
      $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! So it appears that all my code was fine, the 'except' option in the before filter is available in Laravel 4. It was just the small, yet very important getting the routes around the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, because there is an `public $except;` and `public $only;` property in `Filter` class in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Filter.php` file and you can also use `only` instead of `except` to use a filter only on specific methods.

From `L4` docs for `only`

```
 $this->afterFilter('log', array('only' => array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
```

So, **this should work too**

```
$this->beforeFilter('log', array('except' => array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
```

In `L3` I've used

```
$this->filter('before', 'auth')->except(array('login', 'login_ajax', 'fb_login'));
```

but didn't use in `L4` but it should work, according to source code and the doc.

Comment: The issue was the way I have my routes positioned. The custom method (adminLogin) that I added to the AdminController had to be registered in the routes.php file before the Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');