# Laravel wildcard for controller routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I defined a `Route` for grouping controller routes and after using this `URL` :

```
http://localhost/alachiq/public/admin/profile
```

it can show profile view. but if user entered:

```
http://localhost/alachiq/public/admin/profile/
```

that redirects to `http://localhost/admin/profile` and I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin/profile was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.6 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

how to use a wildcard in controller?

my Route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin' ,'before'=>'auth'), function(){
    Route::controller('profile', 'ProfileController',array('getIndex'=>'profile.index', 'postUpdate'=>'profile.update'));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your DocumentRoot should be /path/to/alachiq/public, but if you want it to stay how it is here, you have to modify the htaccess to take the subfolders into account.
It would look like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /alachiq/public/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you are searching for this:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    function __construct() {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('store', 'update')));
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    }
}
```

You can found more code: [Laravel 4 except filter in controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076011/laravel-4-except-filter-in-controller-constructor)